# How can I run ng lint and detect errors on pre-commit?

Tags: angular, bash, githooks, lint

I've got a problem with my pre-commit script. I'm trying to run "ng lint" of my angular project  pre-commit file; I see the errors on logs when detects lint errors but the pre-commit processs pass sucessfully.
I need to do ng-lint in pre-commit file because I'm going to run other validations... How can I get the message when the ng lint dont pass sucessfully?

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

### other scripts to validate custom commits

-----------



### Run ng lint

echo "pre-commit hook --> linting" ng lint

ng lint

echo -e "ng lint pass sucessfully \n\n"
```

Log

```
pre-commit hook --> linting
Linting "front-firefly-backoffice"...
/home/apanez/Escritorio/htdocs/eci/front-firefly/src/app/stock/limit-sale/components/limit-sale-detail/limit-sale-detail.component.ts:30:14
ERROR: 30:14  component-class-suffix  The name of the class LimitSaleDetailComp should end with the suffix Component (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-03)

Lint errors found in the listed files.

ng lint pass sucessfully
```

Comment: Use subshell to capture `ng lint` output with `LINTMSG="$(ng lint)"`. The `ng lint` will probably return 0 for successful completion and anything else when failing. You can then test that with `if [ $? != 0 ]; then { processing error from $LINTMSG }`.

Comment: Thank you!!! What's is ? in the [ $? != 0 ]

Comment: `$?` is set with the exit code of the last executed command. Most of commands (built-in or not) will return 0 for success and anything else for failure. I'll suggest you to read bash man page, section _Special parameters_.

Comment: I will!!. I'm sorry because I not know a lot about bash commands and thanks!!

Comment: `set -e` in your shell script will make erroring subcommands an error

Answer (score 8):

### Fixing lint issues on commit

You can fix all lint issues automatically upon commit.

Here are the steps:

Use eslint (substitute YOUR_PROJECT_NAME with the name of your angular project)

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
```

Install the eslint rules plugin so that you can setup JSON rules:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-json
```

Update `.eslintrc.json` to use the plugin:

```json
{
  "extends": ["plugin:json/recommended"],
   ...
}
```

Install prettier, husky, and lint-staged

```
npm install --save-dev prettier husky lint-staged
```

install husky globally:

```
npm install husky -g
```

Install git hooks (this will create the `.husky` folder):

```
husky install
```

setup lint-staged by adding the following to `package.config`:

```
  "devDependencies: {
     ...
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,json,css,scss,md,ts,html}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  }
```

Optional: Try lint-staged to test your configuration so far

```
npx lint-staged
```

Add the pre-commit git hook:

```
husky add .husky/pre-commit "npx lint-staged"
```

Modify `package.json` to add a post-install step to install husky:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "husky install && husky add .husky/pre-commit \"npx lint-staged\"",
   ...
},
```

### Testing your setup

Modify some .ts, json, or .html files

```
git add *
git commit -m "updated"
```

You should see:

```
[STARTED] Preparing...
[SUCCESS] Preparing...
[STARTED] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Running tasks for *.{js,json,css,scss,md,ts,html}
[STARTED] prettier --write
[SUCCESS] prettier --write
[STARTED] eslint --fix
[SUCCESS] eslint --fix
[SUCCESS] Running tasks for *.{js,json,css,scss,md,ts,html}
[SUCCESS] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Applying modifications...
[SUCCESS] Applying modifications...
[STARTED] Cleaning up...
[SUCCESS] Cleaning up...
[master 20fdf85] updated
```

Comment: You should change 
` husky add .husky/pre-commit \"npx lint-staged\"` with ` husky set .husky/pre-commit \"npx lint-staged\"` otherwise 'add' command will add a new `npx lint-staged` in your pre-commit fil each time you run npm install.

Comment: OP asked for pre-commit hook to run a script. 
While your solution may work, it does not answer the question.